# vhosts conf for single page app

Tags: angularjs, apache, single-page-application

I have an angular app that I'm serving locally using apache. My vhosts.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my.app.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /export/www/app
  <Directory "/export/www/app">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$1 [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to the root of the app everything loads fine. I do some navigation within the app which brings me to my.app.com/some/location and still no problem.

However if I reload the page at this point I get a 404 error. To get back to the point I want I need to either go back to the root and navigate via the app again or else search by url my.app.com/#/some/location

Is there something that I can do with a rewrite rule so that I don't need the hash to reload the route? I tried to edit my existing rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/#/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated
C

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a newer version of apache where the config rules have changed. My updated vhosts now reads

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my.app.com
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /export/www/app
  <Directory "/export/www/app">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Amazed this doesn't have more votes, first result for "apache single page app" on google... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that my.app.com/some/location works. With AcceptPAthInfo ON, httpd would serve index.html and pass PATH_INFO of /some/location but that shouldn't do the right thing on the client-side JS.

The rewrite you attempted seems like it shiould replace your existing rewrite entirely.  But, you'd want to redirect explicitly to non-relative /index.html and add the [R] flag to make sure the redirect goes all the way to the client.  Otherwise, it's just an internal substitution, and you need your browser to read the # because that's only handled on the client side.